# Genus of the graph complement

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

Suppose a simple undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices has [(minimum) genus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphGenus.html) $g$. What is the genus of its [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph)?

My intuitive guess is that the answer is something like

$$\text{genus of }K_n - g$$

but I wasn't able to find any information on this topic online. Is there a known solution to this problem?

This is my first time on MathOverflow, so I apologize if my question is missing something -- thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you add the definition of *genus* of a graph (or a link)?

Comment: If $G$ is any graph on five vertices, other than $K_5$ or its complement, then both $G$ and its complement are planar, while $K_5$ isn't.

Comment: @M.Winter I take it to be the minimum $g$ such that the graph has a 2-cell embedding into a surface of genus $g$.

Comment: Your intuitive guess can be off by something linear in $n$: clearly $K_{n-2,2}$ is planar, its complement $K_{n-2}$ (plus an isolated edge) has genus $(n-5)(n-6)/12$, which is $\approx n/3$ less than the genus of $K_n$.

Comment: To get a feeling and some (counter-)examples one could play around with known coloring results and the coloring-genus-connection given by the [Hadwiger conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_conjecture) (now a theorem).

Comment: @M.Winter I added a definition for graph genus (which concurs with that given by Gerry Myerson). To clarify, is your suggestion to search for results on the chromatic number of the graph complement, then apply the theorem to generate a bound on the genus?